# MPMoviePlayerViewController problem with presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

the problem is that if the movie has finished, the dismissMoviePlayerViewController is called automatically.
This means that the MoviePlayerViewController disappear, but I want he should be on screen if the movie has finished and only the 'Done' Button should do the dismiss...

here is my code:

```
- (void) buttonTapped:(id)sender {
 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dishes" ofType:@"mov"]];
 MPMoviePlayerViewController *movViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

 [url release];
 if(movViewController) {
  [movViewController.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:NO];
  [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movViewController];
 }
}
```

Even the [movViewController.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:NO]; does nothing.

Thank you for answering
xnz

Comment: What do you mean dismissMoviePlayerViewController is called automatically? I use this class every day and you have to manually remove the view.

Comment: ok... first I call presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated, then the movie plays till the end, then the MPMoviePlayerViewController disappears without a call to dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated. I do this in a simple Test-Project. I call the present... from a UIViewController subclass. I add the viewControllers.view with [self.window addSubview:viewController.view]; in AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with what you are seeing versus what is actually happening. While the movie plays, the controls, including the Done button, are hidden. When the movie ends, they stay hidden. To un-hide them, the user has to touch the display somewhere, and the controls will reveal themselves - the VCR controls as well as the Done button and progress slider.